# Can I use mach_star/mach_override on IOS?If not, how should I do?

Tags: iphone, ios, hook

I want to hook some socket functions(such as send, recv,etc) on IOS.

When I'm ready to use mach_star/mach_override, found that it seems to be only available on Mac OS X.So，Who can help me out？

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Definitely not. You won't be able to inject to another processes -- that is technically disallowed, since your app is running in a sandbox and doesn't have access to other processes. It might work on your own process, but what's the point of that?

Comment: Thank you, kuba. I just need to hook socket APIs in my own process.

Comment: If you want this for debugging purposes, you can simply add a breakpoint to any external function. Just do a "break send" command in the GDB/LLDB console.